# image bind to imageView from remote servers data

Tags: android, kotlin, server

```kotlin
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        championsViewModel.mutableChampionList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, ::championListObserver)
        championsViewModel.getAllChampions()
    }


    private fun championListObserver(response: ChampionsResponse) {

        view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.chmpName)?.text = response.data.Aatrox.name.toString()
        view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.chmpTitle)?.text = response.data.Aatrox.title.toString()
        view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.chmpImage) = response.data.Aatrox.image.full
    }
}
```

How do I print the incoming remote server image data to the screen with imageView?

Comment: Use Glide for this https://github.com/bumptech/glide to load url from into imagesView